# How to display associated product weight in the front end on dropdown selection for configurable product?

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento. Building a site which requires a configurable product. The size options are lenght,breadth and height. This appears in a single dropdown (L*B*H) in the product detail page. After selecting a size, the corresponding associated products weight needs to be displayed below. I am not able to locate or figure out 2 things.

1) On change event for dropdown of associated products

2) How to get the weight parameter of selected associated product.

I am working on magento CE 1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

first create the a new weight attribute type is dropdown and it should be apply to configurable products.give the values to weight attibute at manage labels/options tab and finally check it in front end.
  i think its working.otherwise sorry

thanx,
Ram Sampathi